# Using jinja2 (with flask) inside JavaScript script tags to render data

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, chartist.js

As the question states, I simply want to pass and render the results of a list (passed from the main.py file in a flask project) to a html template (charts.html). The issue is that I am trying to put the jinja variable or use jinja inside of script tags (JavaScript) and not the html. I cannot find any documentation or answers that tell me how to do this:

**My code: charts.html** (template in flask)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <title>Webscraping and Charts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Webscraping and Beautiful Charts</h1>
<p>{{enrolled}}</p>
<div class="ct-chart .ct-perfect-fifth"></div>

<script>
var data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    [15, 222, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
};
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data); //this line creates the chart
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Under the h1 tag, you'll notice:

{{enrolled}}

The contents of this variable is defined in the python file. Function showed below.
enrolled=[3,200,600,1800,22000]

```
@app.route('/charts')
def charts():
    enrolled=[3,200,600,1800,22000]
    return render_template('charts.html',enrolled=enrolled)
```

What I would like is for the contents of enrolled to be displayed instead of the existing list in the script tags.

So, replace  [15, 222, 4, 2, 0] in the script tags with the contents of enrolled.

I have tried various things, and it does not work.

For instance, I tried putting the jinja variable inside the list that renders the list like below.

```
<script>
var data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    [{{enrolled}}]
  ]
};
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data); //this line creates the chart
</script>
```

This doesn't work.

Can anyone suggest a solution with an explanation for best practices when trying to use jinja2 inside of JavaScript to render data to an html page, in this case list data for a chart using chartist.js

**Update:**

I have also researched a solution that involves using jquery and ajax to render the results (no jinja2 used at all), but this seems overly complex for what I am trying to achieve.

Please, in your answers, suggest the best solutions/alternatives but my main question is whether or not it can be easily achieved using jinja2

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a relatively old question but as I needed to achieve a similar thing to @MissComputing, I'm sharing this solution that I found. It's not pretty, but it does the job.

So in your case, you'd need to do this:

```
<!-- This SET is just to illustrate an example data source, the data would probably come from you controller -->
{% set enrolled_data = '[3,200,600,1800,22000]' %}

<!-- place a hidden field somewhere in your template to "hold" your data -->
<input type="hidden"  id="enrolled_id" value="{{ enrolled_data }}">

<!-- Now Javascript can look for the hidden field and get the data out of it -->
<script>
var data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    document.querySelector('#enrolled_id').value
  ]
};
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data); //this line creates the chart
</script>
```

***Credits***: This solution is based on the suggestion from one of the comments from a Reddit user in the following post: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/aj06vb/jinja2_into_javascript/

Comment: is ```enrolled_data``` a list or string

Comment: @ConstantineWesterink : In my case, it is a string of: `[3,200,600,1800,22000]`